# Why does Snyk GitHub Actions fail due to ".. Your package.json and undefined are probably out of sync ..."

Tags: github, github-actions, snyk

Hello StackOverflowians.

I'm currently trying to set up Snyk in my GitHub Actions workflow, in a Node project.
The idea is to run two jobs:

1. A Snyk security gate as per their documentation ([found here](https://github.com/snyk/actions/tree/master/node)), such as the first example for keeping it simple.
2. A build and push job (that works as intended on its own)

However, when attempting to run the first job, it fails with the following log during the "Run Snyk to check for vulnerabilities" step:

```
Run snyk/actions/node@master
  with:
    command: test
    json: false
  env:
    REGISTRY: ghcr.io
    IMAGE_NAME: <IMAGENAME>
    SNYK_TOKEN: ***
/usr/bin/docker run --name snyksnyknode_3aa871 --label 6a6825 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e REGISTRY -e IMAGE_NAME -e SNYK_TOKEN -e INPUT_ARGS -e INPUT_COMMAND -e INPUT_JSON -e SNYK_INTEGRATION_NAME -e SNYK_INTEGRATION_VERSION -e HOME -e GITHUB_JOB -e GITHUB_REF -e GITHUB_SHA -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER -e GITHUB_RUN_ID -e GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER -e GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS -e GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT -e GITHUB_ACTOR -e GITHUB_WORKFLOW -e GITHUB_HEAD_REF -e GITHUB_BASE_REF -e GITHUB_EVENT_NAME -e GITHUB_SERVER_URL -e GITHUB_API_URL -e GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL -e GITHUB_REF_NAME -e GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED -e GITHUB_REF_TYPE -e GITHUB_WORKSPACE -e GITHUB_ACTION -e GITHUB_EVENT_PATH -e GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_ACTION_REF -e GITHUB_PATH -e GITHUB_ENV -e RUNNER_OS -e RUNNER_ARCH -e RUNNER_NAME -e RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE -e RUNNER_TEMP -e RUNNER_WORKSPACE -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN -e ACTIONS_CACHE_URL -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/SOMEPROJECT/SOMEPROJECT":"/github/workspace" snyk/snyk:node  "snyk" "test" "--severity-threshold=high --fail-on=upgradable"
Dependency bindings was not found in undefined. Your package.json and undefined are probably out of sync. Please run "undefined" and try again.
```

The last part `Dependency bindings was not found in undefined. Your package.json and undefined are probably out of sync. Please run "undefined" and try again.` is that which I do not understand how it helps me debug.

Is this a known problem with a known solution? If not, how can I go about finding what undefined is referring to?

Thank you in advance,
Raoul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, it seems as though deleting `node_modules/` <s>as well as `package-lock.json`</s> and regenerating them with `npm install` remedies this issue.

```
<in root>
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

Comment: It worked for me, no need for `rm package-lock.json` though ;)